# collapse and expand onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

```js
    // Schließen Button Hauptnavigation
    $('button#collapse-button').click(function () {
        $('nav#main-nav').toggleClass('closed');
    });
    
    
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500) {        
            $('nav#main-nav').addClass('closed');  
        }
    })
```

```css
#header{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:darkslateblue;
}
#content{
  background:#ccc;
  height:900px;
  width:100%;
} 
#main-nav{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:50px;
  transition:all 400ms ease;
}
.closed{
  left:-200px !important;
}
#collapse-button{
  float:right;
  width:20px;
  background:yellow;
}
.closed button{
  margin-right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
header
<br><br>
<nav id="main-nav">
  <button id="collapse-button">X</button>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
  content
</div>
```

Hi all,
the navigation collapse after i scroll 500px down.
But if i open the navigation under the 500px(under purple header-div) by click  and try to scroll, the navigation collapse again.

Can the click behavior are above the scroll behavior ? That is , if you've opened or closed manually by clicking that scrolling the navigation is no longer affected..

sry for bad english

Comment: You can make a boolean variable and set it to false if you click the button. Then in your scroll function you can check if that boolean is false, and if it is, don't execute the function - https://jsfiddle.net/95g81nr6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that once the user has clicked on the button to hide/show, then scroll code should  not execute then , in click [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the scroll event.

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

This will stop monitoring the scroll changes.

```js
// Schließen Button Hauptnavigation
    $('button#collapse-button').click(function () {
        $('nav#main-nav').toggleClass('closed');
        $(window).off('scroll');
    });
    
    
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500) {        
            $('nav#main-nav').addClass('closed');  
        }
    })
```

```css
#header{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:darkslateblue;
}
#content{
  background:#ccc;
  height:900px;
  width:100%;
} 
#main-nav{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:50px;
  transition:all 400ms ease;
}
.closed{
  left:-200px !important;
}
#collapse-button{
  float:right;
  width:20px;
  background:yellow;
}
.closed button{
  margin-right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
header
<br><br>
<nav id="main-nav">
  <button id="collapse-button">X</button>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
  content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean flag to indicate if the menu was clicked like so:

```
    var openedByClick = false;
    // Schließen Button Hauptnavigation
    $('button#collapse-button').click(function () {
        $('nav#main-nav').toggleClass('closed');
        openedByClick = true;
    });


    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500 && !openedByClick) {        
            $('nav#main-nav').addClass('closed');  
        }
    })
```

**Hint:** Its not he nicest solution to introduce a global variable.